# XAudio2 delayed sound - when playing multiple voices

Tags: c++, audio, windows-8, xaudio2

I am using XAudio2 to play sounds in my game. I have about 16 source voices out of which 3 are looping effects which need to be played just like a background music. I have another background music which starts playing at regular intervals(once completed it waits for 1 minute and restarts). Whenever another effect has to be played like button click, gun shot etc, I search for an available source and attach the buffer to it and starts playing.

My problem is once the background music has started playing, just the looping effects will get played and other effects which need to be played on game actions(such as button click) do not get played. And all of these delayed effects get played once the background music is stopped. Also if I use one looping effect(instead of 3) all these get played in the right order.

I am using a submix voice for effects and background music is submitted directly to the mastering voice.

Can someone please help me as I am stuck here

Comment: Did you try to use separate threads to play your audio effects?

Comment: Each time a play sound request is made, I am creating a task for playing it

Comment: I understand, but I believe you are running them in the same thread, so it waits for the effect to complete and THEN play the next effect. You need to create separate threads to display the different effects so they can be displayed concurrently in the same time.

Comment: I was using tasks for playing the sound and I realized that create_task doesn't guarantee that the tasks run on a different thread, once I tried using IAsyncAction, it worked fine

Comment: Please check out my answer. It sums up our conversation and the solution found for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever one intends to play different sounds in the same time, he or she should make sure that these sounds are not in a queue, displayed in a sequential order, but they are displayed using different threads.

In Milsim's case the problem was exactly this, apparently, he used tasks to display the sounds, but they were not issued in different threads. He solved his problem using `IAsyncAction`.